# node.js pulling file form S3 to local

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Currently i am trying to load a file from S3 into my temp file. i am using Node.js running on lambda.

Here is the code i am trying to use

```
            var options = {
                Bucket: 'my_bucket',
                Key: dstKey
            };
            var input   = './temp.pdf';

            var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(input);
            s3.getObject(options).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

I have also tried using the __dirname in my input path with the same results.

I keep getting a file write error.

2016-06-14T19:31:02.859Z    5ea0381c-3266-11e6-a2e3-312b48485905    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './temp.pdf' at Error (native)

Comment: You only have permissions to write to the `/tmp` directory within the AWS Lambda environment.

Comment: that was the answer thanks